# Fill the area with a different color from the line color

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am relatively new to nvd3. I am using the nvd3 linechart module (http://nvd3.org/examples/line.html) to plot multiple graphs. I want to color the area between the lines and above a certain y value with yellow while the line color is grey.
Setting area:true (http://cmaurer.github.io/angularjs-nvd3-directives/line.chart.html) allows me to fill it in the same color as the color of linechart.
Is there a way I can write my own color function to override dis behavior?

Comment: It looks like the area gets a class of `nv-area`. You could just target it with your css and set the fill color that way.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks for the prompt reply! Much appreciated!